# getting this error :-org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session while calling it from inside the thread

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public void getReportWidget(){

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
                    try {
                        getCreatorName(users);
                    } catch (BusinessException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
}
public void getCreatorName(Users userObject) {

        try {
            Hibernate.initialize(userObject.getCreator());
            String creator = reportWidget.getCreator();
                        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error");
        }
    }
```

getting this error :-org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: This link will help you -http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/04/orghibernatelazyinitializationException-Could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session-hibernate-java.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
 lazy=false
```

in hibernate configuration file.

This is works